# How to identify item highlighted in blue on the list and check its associated checkbox in UIPath?

Tags: uipath, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

On the selection screen of an application there is a Search field and Search button
[image]

Once the bot typed in a specific value from an excel file into the search field then click Search.. The search result/item is highlighted in blue.. I would like the bot to identify the highlighted item and check its associated checkbox.. anyone  who has an idea how to? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the "Select Item" Activity? You might find that you can get the result without using the Search bar.

Comment: @craig157 it says the indicated target is not a valid element for the SelectItem action. I think it doesn't work on checkbox list

Comment: Is this an internal/client application or is it public? Just so I could maybe try and give it a go. You might find that you need to add some wildcards against certain factors of the selector.

Comment: If you can search and know that the first result is going to be who you are looking for, then just use a Click Activity, but move the Target Selector from the Standard center of the selector to over the Checkbox.

Comment: Hi @craig157, thanks for the help it's working now.. It worked with Click Image activity, then I just used a dynamic variable on its selector using UI Explorer.